# Create custom search view to search based on two fields in one2many field along with the other fields present in the module

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, erp, one2many

I created a module for managing employee resume in Odoo. Employees will fill their work_experience, education, technology-wise experience, etc. I wanted to make the search view search for all these parameters. The technology-wise Experience here is a One2Many field. I wanted to search this field based on both the parameter together (i.e experience and technology). Please help me find a way to do this.

In Model

```
    technology_experience = 
    fields.One2many("hr.employee.work.technology.experience", 
    inverse_name='resume_id', string='Technology Experience')
```

In view

```
`<field name="technology_experience">
    <tree editable="bottom" create="0">
        <field name="name" required="1"/>
        <field name="experience" required="1"/>
    </tree>
</field>
`
```

Comment: what do you mean by search, like in list view you search employee with some experience? you want to filter employee by there experience and you want to do that in employee search view?

Comment: do you mean you want a form view that can search this two field as parameter and display employee's info? just like [this](https://imgur.com/UAX4aWr) ?

Comment: I need a tree view which can search these two fields together (i.e technology-wise experience) along with the other fields